# Rails test environment URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url, automated-tests

Our Rails 4 application lets other applications communicate with it via an XML API.  In my local dev environment, the URL used by those external scripts is just http://localhost:3000/api_method_name.

What I don't see anywhere in the documentation is a URL that can be used to have external scripts access the test environment.  I'm just using the built-in unit and functional tests at the moment.

I currently have tests set up to interact with the dev environment, but that's hard to write, harder to read, and it means those tests can only run when the dev environment is also up and running.

Comment: In order to isolate your tests you can (and must in order to speed up the suite) mock external requests on your own or by using any framework that helps you, for example with [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). I recommend you to place those responses under `test/support/**` or `spec/support/**` directories depending on your testing framework.

Comment: I'm not sure that would accomplish what I'm talking about, though.  If I have a dummy script that uses curl to access the system, that script won't have access to any mocks, will it?  Or is that functionality something a framework will provide?

Comment: You have to test your API in isolation, then the clients (curl or other) will use that API.